# Prebuild error when build in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, pre-build-event

I know this a similar question has asked previously, but I'm still unable to  find the solution. The error I'm getting is the following:

> Error 2   The command "Copy "C:\ProjectTFS\Vedaleon\BatikAirMalaysia-branch\BatikAirAgentsAutoReport..\MalindoAirCommon\SharedFiles\MalindoDataCredentials.xml" C:\ProjectTFS\Vedaleon\BatikAirMalaysia-branch\BatikAirAgentsAutoReport\SourceControl_Data" exited with code 1. BatikAirAgentsAutoReport

Here is my prebuild event:

> Copy "$(ProjectDir)..\MalindoAirCommon\SharedFiles\MalindoDataCredentials.xml" $(ProjectDir)\SourceControl_Data

Comment: I don't like this part of path `BatikAirAgentsAutoReport..`. should it be `BatikAirAgentsAutoReport\..`?

Comment: My Mistake,  reference name got changed to BatikAirCommon on file rename.

Answer (score 0):

the reference was wrong .the folder name was batikAirCommon